# GDAL: write to zip archive

Tags: python, gdal

I know that starting version 2.2, `gdal` has virtual filesystem drivers, like `/vsizip/` for accessing `zip` archives.

Previously I've been able to read from `zip` archives, but I haven't manage to write to them (which should also be possible I guess). I didn't find much documentation about this either.

This is what I tried:

```
import gdal
from zipfile import ZipFile
import numpy as np

with ZipFile('test.zip','a') as zfile:
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    raster = driver.Create('/vsizip/test.zip/testraster.tif',10,10, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    raster.GetRasterBand(1).writeArray(np.random.random(10,10))
    raster = None
```

But I'm always receiving

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

**EDIT:**

Updated the snipped as per Gabriella Giordano's suggestion.

**EDIT 2**:

Gabriella pointed out that the `GTiff` driver needs both read and write access at the same time, which is (currently?) not supported.

The suggested workaround is creating a temporary file and then copy it into the archive.

I'm really interested into directly creating a raster file (doesn't have to be a tiff) inside the archive. If I wanted to copy them, I might as well use `zipfile` or the like.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 3**:

Full disclosure*, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

I have MODIS `hdf` files, and I want to directly save the value raster subdatasets into a zip archive.

**Solution**:

I've finally managed to do it with the excellent insight from Gabriella.

I ended up using `gdal.Translate` with this passed in to `options`:

`gdal.TranslateOptions(creationOptions=['STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=TRUE'])`

---

*I did't think this was pertinent information, but Gabriela's answer makes me think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really fluent in python, but the dataset creation is probably failing because you are not setting the number of bands.

Try this:

```
raster = driver.Create('/vsizip/test.zip/testraster.tif',10,10, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
```

Change 1 with the desired number of bands.

You can find the complete list of arguments of Create [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220531203731/https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-pysrc.html#Driver.Create).

EDIT:

Found the possible cause of the issue (and a possible workaround) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805792/gdal-cannot-create-and-write-a-zip-file-with-vsizip). As reported at this [link](https://gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html#gdal_virtual_file_systems_vsizip), apparently the open mode of Create is incompatible with the vsizip virtual filesystem.

Edit 2

This is not a problem of the driver you use (e.g. GeoTiff), but a problem of the virtual file system itself.
The Create call tries to open a file in both read/write mode because GDAL uses the file system as a cache for performance reasons, not only for storage. But in this case, the virtual vsizip file system does not allow to read and write from a file at the same time, because it does not support random access.

The vsizip vfs indeed provides on-the-fly reads and writes separately, because it compress/decompress data for you in the background. This means that you cannot jump back and forth (as in random access mode requested for read/write open mode) because what you write on disk (compressed data) is different from what you could eventually read (uncompressed data).

Edit 3

I've found out that gdal command line tools (like gdal_translate or  gdal_warp) set the 'STREAMABLE_OUTPUT = TRUE' *automagically* when working with virtual file systems. A streamable file format enforces a Write only policy that should comply with non-random access file systems. You can set this option as an additional parameter for the Create call. Again my limited python capabilities prevent me from providing a working snippet.

Please consider though, that *steamable* also implies some limitation on the kind of operations that you can perform on the dataset, so this is probably not going to fix your problem, but it is useful to know anyway...

Comment: +1 for spotting an error. Unfortunately the original problem remains ... gdal doesn't create a tiff inside the zip archive. Even without specifying the band, it should create a dataset with the wrong number of bands (`gdal.GDT_Float32` resolves to 6).

Comment: Very interesting, I was aware of the documentation, but it didn't say that the GeoTiff driver would need both accesses at the same time. Please see my recent edit for additional comment

Comment: I tried to improve my answer again, as it was not clear enough. Hope this explains better the issue (not of the driver) but of the vsizip file system.

Comment: Very nice explanation! So to sum it up, it is not possible to write a raster directly to a zipfile? Maybe using `gdal_translate` instead of `Create`? The documentation does say after all: _They allow creating a new zip file and adding new files to an already existing (or just created) zip file._

Comment: good point. See my last edit on it (too long for a comment) :)